# How to print only on odd page in twoside document?

Tags: page-breaking, memoir

I'm writing a booklet for kids. At the end I want to insert material to be cut (puzzles, pictures…).

My question is how to insert blank pages to ensure the printing only on odd pages at the end?

Thank you.

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{easyfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\gdef\adecouper{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ImageADecouper}{om}{\textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:#2} p.~\pageref{fig:#2}.} \g@addto@macro\adecouper{\Figure[here, #1]{#2}}}
\makeatother
\AtEndDocument{\cleartorecto Pictures to be cut. Must be printed on odd pages…\adecouper}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test}]{example-image}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test a}]{example-image-a}
    
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test b}]{example-image-b}
    
    \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses paracol to separate odd and even pages.  You might want to look at the endfloat package as well.

So easyfig can split captions from figures?  Interesting, but not in a good way.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{easyfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{paracol}

\gdef\adecouper{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ImageADecouper}{om}{\textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:#2} p.~\pageref{fig:#2}.} \g@addto@macro\adecouper{\Figure[here, #1]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test}]{example-image}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test a}]{example-image-a}
    
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test b}]{example-image-b}
    
    \lipsum[4]
  \cleartorecto
  \begin{paracol}[1]*{2}
    Pictures to be cut. Must be printed on odd pages…\adecouper
  \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!
I noticed also the split caption… It's due to the option `here`. I changed to `placement=h!` to keep the float mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a slight change to the argument to your `\adecouper` macro adding  `\cleartorecto` before the `\Figure` so each picture at the end will be printed on an odd page.

```
% blankendproc.tex  SE 575493

% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{easyfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\gdef\adecouper{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ImageADecouper}{om}{\textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:#2} p.~\pageref{fig:#2}.}
 \g@addto@macro\adecouper{\cleartorecto\Figure[here, #1]{#2}}}   %%%%% changed this
\makeatother
%%%% moved the argument to just before \end{document}
%\AtEndDocument{\cleartorecto Pictures to be cut. Must be printed on odd pages…\adecouper}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\leavespergathering{6}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test}]{example-image}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test a}]{example-image-a}
    
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \ImageADecouper[width=\linewidth, caption={Test b}]{example-image-b}
    
    \lipsum[4]

\cleartorecto Pictures to be cut. Must be printed on odd pages…\adecouper

\end{document}
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted some blank pages at the end where you could paste different materials after printing. I used the `memoir` macro `\leavespergathering{<num>}` to do this which will produce a multiple of `2num` pages, with blank pages at the end to make up the number if necessary (see section *Gatherings or signatures* in the manual).

Comment: I tried this, but sometimes the pictures are quite small. So I wanted TeX computes the pagebreaks in a more clever way!
By the way, why do you remove the \AtEnDocument?

Comment: If your pictures are small and you want more on a page you have to change the float placement parameters. I'm sure there there are answers to this, including one from me but I can't find them so see section **Where LaTeX Puts Floats** in the `memoir` manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

Comment: When I used `leavespergathering` the `\AtEndDocument` could produce a series of blank page between the end of your main text and the start of your end pictures. I changed the `\ImageADecouper` to eliminate the need for `\AtEndDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple approach.

```
% !TeX encoding = utf8
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{easyfig}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\gdef\adecouper{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\@arabic\c@figure}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ImageADecouper}{om}{\textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:#2} p.~\pageref{fig:#2}.} \g@addto@macro\adecouper{\Figure[here, #1]{#2}}}
\makeatother
%\AtEndDocument{\cleartorecto Pictures to be cut. Must be printed on odd pages…\adecouper}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  1.  \lipsum[1]
  
  \textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:TestA} p.~\pageref{fig:TestA}.}
    
 2.  \lipsum[2]
 
  \textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:TestB} p.~\pageref{fig:TestB}.}
    
  3.  \lipsum[3]
  
    \textbf{Use picture \cref{fig:TestC} p.~\pageref{fig:TestC}.}

 4.   \lipsum[4]
 
 \chapter*{Pictures to be cut}
 
  \cleardoublepage
 
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-A}
    \caption{Test A}
    \label{fig:TestA}
\end{figure}
    
   
    \cleardoublepage
    
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-B}
    \caption{Test B}
    \label{fig:TestB}
\end{figure}

 \cleardoublepage

    
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-C}
    \caption{Test C}
    \label{fig:TestC}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: A]

[image: B]

Comment: That was a possibility. But I wished to insert the material in the flow avoiding the manual insertion at the very end of my (very) long document :)